# Posting to feed in LinkedIn API v2

Tags: php, linkedin-api

Does LinkedIn API V2 allows to post on feed? I trying to use /shares and /ugcPosts endpoints but my item published only in Activity section of my profile, not on my feed.

That is my request body

```
   "author" => $urn,
   "lifecycleState" => "PUBLISHED",
   "specificContent" => [
         "com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent" => [
                "shareCommentary" => [
                        "attributes" => [],
                        "text" => "Some share text"
                 ],
                 "shareMediaCategory" => 'NONE',
          ]
   ],
   "visibility" => [
          "com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility" => "PUBLIC"
   ]
]'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you've submitted a POST /ugcPosts and you receive a 201 response, your post has been created on your feed. You should also receive the ugcPost id as part of the header response.